# change user entered character inside an EditText in Android

Tags: java, android, android-edittext, android-softkeyboard

I want to change user entered character in a EditText. in fact i want  when user types in Edit text, If input character is "S", replaces it with "B" character.  i want do this realtime.

Comment: You can use the TextWatcher. http://developer.android.com/reference/android/text/TextWatcher.html

Answer (score 7, accepted):

> I want to change user entered character in a EditText. in fact i want
>   when user types in Edit text, If input character is "S", replaces it
>   with "B" character. i want do this realtime.

Most likely you need to use [`TextWatcher`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/text/TextWatcher.html) that it pretty designated for your goal and allows you to manipulate with content of EditText in realtime.

**Example:**

```
edittext.addTextChangedListener(new TextWatcher() {

    public void onTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int before, int count) {           

    }

    public void beforeTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int count, int after) {    

    }

    public void afterTextChanged(Editable s) {

    }
});
```

Comment: can you give me a real example? id what you say but i cant get what i want. please

Comment: @FarhadShirzad type on google.com textwatcher android example. you can start [here](http://www.android-ever.com/2012/06/android-edittext-textwatcher-example.html)

Comment: yes, i think it works and im working on it right now. thank you

Answer (score 2):

Like Sajmon explained, you have to implement a TextWatcher. You have to take care for the cursor. Because the user can input the next character (or a sequence from the clipboard) at any position in the existing text string. To handle this, you have to change the character at the right position (don't replace the whole text):

```
        damageEditLongText.addTextChangedListener(new TextWatcher() {

        @Override
        public void beforeTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int count, int after) {}

        @Override
        public void onTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int before, int count) {}

        @Override
        public void afterTextChanged(Editable s) {
            // Nothing to replace
            if (s.length() == 0)
                return;

            // Replace 'S' by 'B'
            String text = s.toString();
            if (Pattern.matches(".*S.*", text)) {
                int pos = text.indexOf("S");
                s.replace(pos, pos + 1, "B");
            }
        }
    });
```

Answer (score 0):

use

```
EditText textField = findViewById(R.id.textField);
String text = textField.getText().toString();
```

then you can use

```
text.replace('b','s');
```

followed by

```
textField.setText(text,TextView.BufferType);
```

TextView.BufferType can have 3 values as stated [here](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/TextView.BufferType.html)